# How to merge all models in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I want to show all slideshow when the images are not blank.

```
public function index()
{
    $slideAdvertise = Advertise::whereNotNull('image')->get();
    $slideDesignStudio = DesignStudio::whereNotNull('image')->get();
    $slideHouse = House::whereNotNull('image')->get();
    $slidePhotographer = Photographer::whereNotNull('image')->get();
    $slideWebsite = Website::whereNotNull('image')->get();
    $slideShows = $slideAdvertise->merge($slideDesignStudio)->merge($slideHouse)->merge($slidePhotographer)->merge($slideWebsite);
    return view('Home.index', compact('slideShows'));
}
```

**Note:** This code does not even have an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you are missing.

First the `all()` function at the end of the merge calls.

```
$slideShows = $slideAdvertise->merge($slideDesignStudio)->merge($slideHouse)->merge($slidePhotographer)->merge($slideWebsite)->all();
```

Second is to use arrays in case a query returns no results.

```
public function index()
{
    $slideAdvertise = Advertise::whereNotNull('image')->get()->toArray();
    $slideDesignStudio = DesignStudio::whereNotNull('image')->get()->toArray();
    $slideHouse = House::whereNotNull('image')->get()->toArray();
    $slidePhotographer = Photographer::whereNotNull('image')->get()->toArray();
    $slideWebsite = Website::whereNotNull('image')->get()->toArray();
    $slideShows = $slideAdvertise->merge($slideDesignStudio)->merge($slideHouse)->merge($slidePhotographer)->merge($slideWebsite)->all();
    return view('Home.index', compact('slideShows'));
}
```